# How to fix my "grub-efi-amd64-signed package failed to install into /target/" problem for ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10

i have this problem during dual booting. I've done dual booting before and absolutely confirmed that I had no flaw during the process. I have windows10 installed.

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with grub. The grub-install wasn't the problem, but rather update-grub, thus the config file for grub is not created.

If the installer has a command line option at the bottom it will make this a lot easier. since you can go back to install grub after making this change. otherwise you will have to finish without installing grub then use a live CD to fix the problem and install grub.

The file /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware is a script for adding the system uefi console to the grub menu. It errors out.

I edited mine to read:

```
set -e
gettext_printf "Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration\n" >&2

cat << EOF

menuentry 'uefi-firmware' {
fwsetup
}

EOF
```

then updated grub.

if you can make this change without leaving the installer, go back to install grub and it should work.

If not then it becomes more complicated but can still be done.